# Not able to get the dbname, rolename, userid, last access date, read/write access for a Snowflake target table

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-data-warehouse

As a part of auditing in my project and I need to find the db name, user name, last access date, read/write access, role name for the tables present in the Snowflake target. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake provides a database view in the "Account Usage" share called "tables", which will provide you a list of all the tables in your Snowflake account, along with their schema, database, and role that owns the table.
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage/tables.html

As for access (reads via `SELECT`, unloads via `COPY INTO LOCATION` commands) 
and writes (`INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE`, and load via `COPY INTO TABLE` commands), 
you can query a different view in the "Account Usage" share called query_history and search for the table name using the `iLike('%tableNameHere%')` function on the `QUERY_TEXT` column which works well.
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html